# MVC return a value from a jqueryui dialog modal

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui

I have a very simple dialog box that opens up on page ready, here is the code

this code is on my view

```
$(document).ready(
        //Dialog
        $("#dialog").dialog({
            title: "Dialog box",
            height: 300,
            modal: true,
            open: function(event, ui) {
                $(this).load("@Url.Action("TestDialogView", "Card")");
            }
        })
    );
```

now this opens up a dialog modal fine with the view contents of TestDialogView. Now what I would like to do is draw a table in the dialog (I can do this with the view), but what I want to try and do is, when the user clicks one of the items in the table, the ID of that item is then posted back to the view we are on, and the id is now passed into my model.

Example with steps

1. step 1: Users loads up the CardTypes page
2. step 2: The dialog box shows up with a list of items
3. step 3: when clicking the "view" link in the table row
4. step 4: the id of that item will be posted back from the dialog
5. step 5: the dialog closes
6. step 6: the variable SelectedId on the CardTypes view model is now populated with the id   posted back from the dialog.

Cheers

---update---

Here is a screen shot of my dialog,

[image]

and here is the view that renders it

```
@model CardSite.Models.FileSearchModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Attacks";
}

<table class="table">
<tr>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(x => x.Name)
    </th>
    <th>
        Select
    </th>
</tr>

@foreach (var item in Model.PokemonFiles)
{
<tr>
    <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(m => item.Name)
    </td>
    <td>
        <a href="">View</a>
    </td>
</tr>
}

</table>
```

What do I need to change in my view? What should the "view" a link be?

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a event delegation with `.on()`:

```
var selectedId = '';
$("#dialog").on('click', '.table a', function(){
    selectedId = this.id;
});
```

---

or if you explain a bit more about your step 4.

---

As per your updated question i don't see any ID in your table or any `tr, td or anchor` is also not having any ID.
So now here i have changed my answer little bit:

```
$("#dialog").on('click', '.table a', function(){
    alert($(this).closest('tr').find('td:first').text());
});
```

---

The above code would give you the first td's text in alert relative to the link clicked.

Comment: well to be honest i'm not 100% sure on step 4, I can draw a table with data from my database, I can then add a link which will link to something and pass the id, i'm not sure how I can pass my ID back from my view to the view the modal on was.

Comment: see if your anchor holds that id then you can use as above posted you can change `viewlink` with any class name if added to that link.

Comment: I will let you know how it goes cheers. I won't tick as answer as i still may need help

Comment: @canvas i don't see any id there.

Comment: The code you have provided where does this go? on my CardTypes view or the view that is draw in the dialog?

Comment: Ok I have placed your code into my modal view and now it is alerting the text from the table, how can I get it so when the "view" is clicked it will close the modal, and then postback the ID value back to the model on cardtypes? I will add the ID value to a table column so we can get it by ID